# how to access a jhipster generated application's api from a standalone react application

Tags: reactjs, spring, keycloak, jhipster, monolithic

I have generated a monolithic application (spring boot, react, keycloak) using jhipster 7.9, and it is fine for the admin panel, for users, I am building a new standalone react expo application, but I want to fetch the data from the generated monolithic api. Till now I am getting an access token from the keycloak server, but what should i do in order to get the data from the api, I have tried to send the access token with the header to the api but got 401 unauthorized error. Notice that I have done nothing to the spring boot application.